# why showMap() function do not run when press button ? how to fix? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

this code fllow is JavaScript, but showMap() do not run ? why ? how to fix ? thank

```
<html>
        <title></title>  
        <script>
        function showMap()
        {       
            alert("rong");
        }
        function thaydoi()
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").value =" anh yeu em";
        }
       </script>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 437px; width: 663px"  onload="chance()">
    <input type="text" id="txtHint" value="" onchange="showMap()" >
    <input type="button" onclick="thaydoi()">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't run? It certainly will with the above, if you change the value of the `txtHint` text box and tab out of it (or otherwise cause it to lose focus).

Comment: i want to when i press button --> alert() show....., but when i press button -> do not show.....Why ? how to fix ?

Comment: @HiếuĐạiNhân If that's what you want you've got the handlers the wrong way around. `onchange="thaydoi()"` and `onclick="showMap()"`

Comment: no, i want to when press button - > alert("rong") show ? can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

`onchange` triggers when the input blurs. Use `onkeypress` instead if required. And if you want to call showMap(), write it in thaydoi().

Below is your modified code:

```
<html>
        <title></title>  
        <script>
        function showMap()
        {       
            alert("rong");
        }
        function thaydoi()
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").value =" anh yeu em";
            showMap();
        }
       </script>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 437px; width: 663px"  onload="chance()">
    <input type="text" id="txtHint" value="">
    <input type="button" onclick="thaydoi()">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's not onkeypress... the text of the input field is set by the js function so there is no key pressed. you should add the call to showMap in the thaydoi function.

Comment: Hi @Jkike ,oops! Answer was mapped on `onchange` written in input field. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking run `showMap()` and for that you need do like :

```
<input type="text" id="txtHint" onchange="showMap()" >
<script>
function showMap()
{
     alert("showMap call!");
}

</script>
```

Or, using simple jQuery:

```
$("#txtHint").keyup( function() {
    var txtHintVal = $("#txtHint").val();
    alert("Call ME >> " . txtHintVal);
});
```

**NOTE:** You need to use the "**onblur**" event. It fires when a control loses its focus, which seems to be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like:

```html
<html>
        <title></title>  
        <script>
        function showMap()
        {       
            alert("rong");
        }
        function thaydoi()
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").value =" anh yeu em";
            showMap();
        }
       </script>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 437px; width: 663px"  onload="chance()">
    <input type="text" id="txtHint" value="" >
    <input type="button" onclick="thaydoi()">
    </body>
    </html>
```